# "Too many indices for array" When trying to define a column of values

Tags: python, index-error

```
data = np.genfromtxt('radondecay.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=0)
print('radon decay =')
print(data)
```

radon decay =
[ 11.  12.  12.  23.  17.  20.  10.  17.  12.  15.  20.  14.  21.  19.

I copied the first line of data onto here, but this goes on for many more lines. The original file is just one column of values.

```
count = data[:,0]
print("counts =", count)

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-8a5c8f0bfbad> in <module>
----> 1 count = data[:,0]
      2 print("counts =", count)

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I looked at other examples of this on the site, but I'm not too good with programming in general so I can't understand the context of most other peoples code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has one dimension (vector as opposed to matrix).

1D is accessed by one index or slice. i.e. data[1] or data[2:5].
You can verify it by `data.shape`

Comment: Thank you, I figured it had something to do with the dimensions. I extracted all the data in the column by using data[0:]. Now i'm wondering, whats the difference between data[0:] and data[:,0], if they both do the same thing? Is the second function defining that I have multiple existent columns?

Comment: They are not the same thing. First is take data from first to end. Later is take the first column of 2d array